# Running Python code (Boto3) remotely (AWS)

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I have code that moves items from one s3 bucket to another. I am running it locally on my computer. However, it will take a long time to finish running as there are many items in the bucket.

```
import boto3
#Get resource
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
#Get reference to buckets
src = s3.Bucket('src')
dst = s3.Bucket('dst')

#Iterate through the items in the source bucket
for item in src.objects.all():
    #Creates a copy of the item?
    copy_source = {
        'Bucket' : 'src',
        'Key' : item.key
    }
    #Places the copy of the item in the destination bucket
    dst.copy(copy_source,'Images/'+item.key)
```

Is there any way I can run this code remotely such that I would not have to monitor it? I have tried AWS lambda but it has a maximum run time of 15 minutes. Is there something like that I could use but for a longer time.

Comment: One of your problems is your program is doing everything sequentially. Really won't matter where you run it. You need to do parallel copies.

Comment: @JohnHanley I see! The reason why I want to run it remotely is because I would have to shut down the computer when I leave. The program would most likely not be done by then. Thus, I would prefer it to be running on a computer that is always "awake" (Remotely)

Comment: Launch an EC2 instance and run your program there.

Comment: @JohnHanley Okay, so now the program is running on the EC2 instance currently. As long as the instance is running, the program will continue to run until it finishes it's execution right? It does not matter if I am logged out?

Comment: When you logged out or your connecting times out your program will be terminated. You can install programs so that your program continues on disconnects. Look into a program called `screen` and `tmux`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [Data Pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/what-is-datapipeline.html).
A data pipeline spawns an EC2 instance where you can run your job.
You can schedule the pipeline to run run at least every 15 minutes. (But not less) 
There is also the option to create a pipeline that you van run on demand.
It also offers a console where you can view the jobs and their outcome and have the opportunity to rerun failed jobs.

For this kind of activity you should probably use this:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-shellcommandactivity.html

Another option is to just start an EC2 instance run your job and then stop it.

Comment: I am trying EC2 now and it works but it seems like overkill. I'll check out Data Pipeline as well. Thanks!